# How to redirect my app to location service in settings

Tags: android

I am developing an application in that I need user current location so if there is no location service is enabled then I created one Alert to set location service but I am not getting to redirect to location settings

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can start an Activity using the Intent below to redirect the user to the settings screen :

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: @ddwaele how to backpress return to app, currently it goes to settings instead of app